# Array is empty on angular typescript page

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ngoninit

I'm filling my string 'Questions' with a function named 'getQuestionsWithInterviewId' but when I call it with the console.log in the ngOnInit and ngAfterContentInit methods it looks empty.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { QuestionService } from '../_services/question.service';
import { Question } from '../_models/model';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-interview',
   templateUrl: './interview.component.html'
 })

 export class InterviewComponent implements OnInit {

 questions: Question[]=[];

 constructor(private questionService: QuestionService) {

 }

 ngOnInit(): void {
 }

 ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.getQuestionsWithInterviewId(1);
    console.log(this.questions);

    $(".tab-wizard").steps({
      headerTag: "h6",
      bodyTag: "section",
      transitionEffect: "fade",
      titleTemplate: '<span class="step">#index#</span> #title#',
      labels: {
        finish: "end"
      },
      onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
        alert("end");
      }
    });

  }

  getQuestionsWithInterviewId(interviewId: number) {
    this.questionService.getQuestionsWithInterviewId(interviewId).subscribe(a => {
    this.questions = a;
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
 }

}
```

[image]

but when I use the 'questions' array on the component.html page, I can see the results.

[image]

[image]

If I do the console.log operation within the 'getQuestionsWithInterviewId' function, I can get results.

```
getQuestionsWithInterviewId(interviewId: number) {
this.questionService.getQuestionsWithInterviewId(interviewId).subscribe(a => {
  this.questions = a;
  console.log(this.questions);
},
  error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
 }
```

[image]

question.service.ts page;

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Question } from '../_models/model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class QuestionService {

  baseUrl: string = 'https://localhost:44388/api/questions/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  getQuestionsWithInterviewId(interviewId: number): Observable<Question[]> {
    return this.http.get<Question[]>(this.baseUrl + 
"GetQuestionsWithInterviewId/" + interviewId);
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `getQuestionsWithInterviewId` uses observable from `questionService`.

`questions` is populated when you assign `this.questions = a`. This happens when subscription is fired. Subscription fires only after all call stack is empty. So this happens right after `ngAfterContentInit` finishes executing.

To perform manupulations with data from subscription, you must do it in a `subscribe` callback.

#### Update

```
ngOnInit() {   
    this.questionService.getQuestionsWithInterviewId(1).subscribe(a => {
      this.questions = a;
      // this console log will do
      console.log(this.questions);
      // feel free to do your magic with questions here
    },
}
```

Comment: how can i do? i shared question.service.ts page

Comment: @pbachman posted functioning example. In his case console log will log questions correctly

Answer (score 0):

you don't need an extra method "getQuestionsWithInterviewId" in your component, you can call the service directly. I would recommend to do it on ngOnInit, like this:

```
ngOnInit() {   
    this.questionService.getQuestionsWithInterviewId(1).subscribe(a => {
      this.questions = a;
      console.log(this.questions);
    },
    error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
    
    $(".tab-wizard").steps({
        headerTag: "h6",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "fade",
        titleTemplate: '<span class="step">#index#</span> #title#',
        labels: {
          finish: "end"
        },
        onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
          alert("end");
        }
     });
}
```